# Define custom validation annotation that extends an existing one - javaEE

Tags: validation, java-ee-6

I want to define a custom `@DateOfBirthValid` validation annotation that makes use of `@Pattern` annotation so that I define the date of birth pattern once and use it wherever ... I know I can define it using `@Constraint(validatedBy = SomeClass.class)` then define the `isValid()` method inside `SomeClass` but I wonder if there is a more direct way to use the `@Pattern` annotation and give it the date of birth regex I want ... the reason is that I want to use the same validation annotation in many places in the code without defining the pattern again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkfgx.html:

> Bean Validation includes several built-in constraints that can be combined to create new, reusable constraints. This can simplify constraint definition by allowing developers to define a custom constraint made up of several built-in constraints that may then be applied to component attributes with a single annotation.

In the example in the link you can see how `@Pattern` is used (amongst others) to create an Email validation annotation:

```
@Pattern.List({
  @Pattern(regexp = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\."
    +"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*"
    +"@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")
})
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,
    ElementType.FIELD,
    ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,
    ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
    ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Email {

    String message() default "{invalid.email}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({ElementType.METHOD,
        ElementType.FIELD,
        ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,
        ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
        ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        Email[] value();
    }
}
```

So from my (rather limited) understanding of this you should be able to create a new annotation *similar* to this

```
@Pattern(regexp = yourRegex)
@Documented
@Target(/* all targets here */)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DateOfBirthValid {
    /* all methods required */
    /* Same thing for the List interface */
}
```

Which then should be usable like

```
@DateOfBirthValid
protected String myString
```

or for the example from the link

> This custom constraint can then be applied to an attribute.

```
...
@Email
protected String email;
...
```

Comment: I also had to use `@Constraint(validatedBy = {})`. Otherwise my custom annotation was ignored (in a Spring Boot service). Using `@Constraint` also requires one to provide `message, groups and payload`.